# How to get all Event Types to appear when reporting on events?

Tags: event, eventlogfile

I am currently attempting to report on several event types (ie Report Export ; Apex Trigger ; BulkAPI etc..) but can only get Login and Logout event types to appear whenever I query the EventLogFile object in Workbench, or if I use the browser tool here :

https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com

I've been trying to figure out why only Login & Logouts will show up. Do I need to "activate" the other event types to be monitored in some way ? I've been going through the different documentation on it and it doesn't seem to require that.

This is the documentation I've used :

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most event types require a subscription. Please note in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm):

> The Insecure External Assets, Login, and Logout events are available in supported Salesforce editions at no additional cost. Contact Salesforce to purchase the remaining event types.

Comment: the cool thing about the subscription is you get a "free" Analytics Dashboard that gives you all the power of Einstein Analytics to look at the generated datasets in a nice visual way (including the ability to set dashboard alerts)